# CheckBox Check is not Working on server side in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am facing issue in Gridview Check box checked and server side checkbox is showing checked = false.

Its really strange and I haven't seen yet before.

I have written following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function SelectAll() {
            if ($('.SelectAll input:checkbox').attr("checked"))
                $('.chkTechs input:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
            else
                $('.chkTechs input:checkbox').attr("checked", false);
        }
        function SetCheckBoxes(item) {
            //$(item).attr("target").checked    // this is to find which element clicked
            if ($('.chkTechs input:checkbox').filter(":not(:checked)").length > 0) {
                $('.SelectAll input:checkbox').attr("checked", false)
            }
            else {
                $('.SelectAll input:checkbox').attr("checked", true)
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Server side Button Click

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvList.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox Checked = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
                bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;
            }
```

Comment: please show us asp code are you using ajax? its better to use clientside ie javascript to select all checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of server controls is maintained in `viewstate` and changing the state of control like you are changing the checked status of checkbox with client script (`javascript`) is not updated in `viewstate`. So when you access the control on server side you do not get the changes. You have to store the changes in some `hidden field` and use that hidden field on server side to update your controls. It is the way asp.net implements the `viewstate`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get their value by checking the existence of Request.Form[xxx] parameter of the corresponding checkbox. In you case [chkSelectXXX].

1) Append something meaningful to the ID of your checkbox while creating it. Ex: the primary key val so that the ID of the checkbox should be [chkSelect_PKValue1]

2) On server side loop through Request.Form variables and check for the existence of variables that have the key value starting with chkSelect. Something like this:

```
foreach(var x in Request.Form)
{
     if(x.StartsWith("chkSelect"))
     {
          //3. Then this checkbox is selected you should parse the 
          //PK value and do what's necessary.
     }
}
```